# Should I use commas when providing one location in a sentence

Tags: punctuation

I am having trouble finding information on whether or not I should use commas in this sentence.  I'm hoping someone on here can help me.

Your physical permit can be picked up from the Transportation Office in Admin Services I building located at 2721 Sullivan Dr. during regular business hours: Monday through Friday, 7 A.M. - 5 P.M.

Should I place a comma after the word building or at; after Dr.; both or neither?  Is there a better way to word this sentence?  Can anyone help me with this?

Your physical permit can be picked up from the Transportation Office in Admin Services I building located at, 2721 Sullivan Dr., during regular business hours: Monday through Friday, 7 A.M. - 5 P.M.

Please let me know if I'm using the colon appropriately too.

Thank you

Comment: I would include the phrase _located at 2721 Sullivan Dr._ between commas - otherwise it implies that the office is only located there during business hours! But questions like this are more suited to the English Language Learners forum.